# If $ f(x)= \int_0^x x^2\sin(t^2)dt$ then $f'(x)= ?$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Since the integral doesn't depend on $x$, I take $x^2$ out of the integral and take the derivative of a constant times a function. The final result is $x^2\sin(x^2)$.

I saw one suggested answer which gives a different answer: $x^2\sin(x^2)+2xf(x)$, which is the derivative using the product rule. Which one is correct? Please explain, thanks.

Comment: Look up the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: The final result is **not** $x^2 \sin^2 x $. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: $f(x)$ is the so-called Fresnel integral

Comment: $x^2$ is constant to the integral but not the function

Comment: Thanks to all and excuse my ignorance, I did not know this function. It comes as an exercise in the textbook I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2$ is a constant with respect to the integral (since it's an integral with respect to $t$) **but** $x^2$ isn't a constant when you differentiate with respect to $x$ (i.e. when you want to compute $f'(x)$).

Thus

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\int_0^x\sin(t^2)dt\right) = \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\right)\underbrace{\int_0^x\sin(t^2)dt}_{=f(x)/x^2} + x^2\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_0^x\sin(t^2)dt\right)$$

which gives $$f'(x) = 2x\dfrac{f(x)}{x^2} + x^2\sin(x^2) = 2\dfrac{f(x)}{x} + x^2\sin(x^2).$$

Comment: Right. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  And yet, somehow, your incorrect solution received up votes. LOL

Comment: Thank you Paf! This is the best answer. Now I understand the solution and the reasoning behind the question. Also thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)$ be given by the integral

$$f(x)=x^2\int_0^x \sin(t^2)\,dt$$

Then, from the product rule we have

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\left(\frac{dx^2}{dx}\right)\left(\int_0^x \sin(t^2)\,dt\right)+\left(x^2\right)\left(\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x \sin(t^2)\,dt\right)\\\\
&=2x\int_0^x \sin^2(t)\,dt+x^2\sin(x^2)\\\\
&=\frac{2f(x)}{x}+x^2\sin(x^2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Good morning! ${}{}$

Comment: Hi Joe!  How are you?

Comment: Failing miserably at Mother's Day again :-)

Comment: My wife just left to visit her older son who lives in Phoenix.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer Mark! This was really helpful.

Comment: Correct answers receive upvotes too LOl +1

Comment: @MarkViola: You get a day pass :-).

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle f(x)= \int_0^x x^2\sin(t^2)dt$$
Apply Leibniz rule:

$$\displaystyle f'(x)=\displaystyle x^2\sin(x^2)+ \int_0^x \partial_x x^2\sin(t^2)dt$$
$$\displaystyle f'(x)=\displaystyle x^2\sin(x^2)+2x\int_0^x \sin(t^2)dt$$
$$\displaystyle f'(x)=\displaystyle x^2\sin(x^2)+2 \frac {f(x)}x$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer Isham!

Comment: yw @É.DD .......